# Converting Counting Sort to Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, counting-sort

I am having issues trying to convert the counting sort algorithm to assembly language.  I seem to be getting caught up in the loops and when i am passing by reference and value.

I dont know if I am referencing my j, i, list, and count correctly.  I also dont know if I am missing parts to the loop.

Comment: It's a histogram followed by a sequence of `memset` fills.  I'd just do it with pointer increments.  Remember that a dword is 4 bytes wide: to increment a pointer or byte offset (like your `r8`) by 1 dword, you need to add `4`, not `inc` by 1.  Also, 32-bit address size for `list[r8d]` seems like a bad idea.  You're using the normal 64-bit address-size for indexing `count[rsi]` with a byte offset.  (But again you should be using `add esi,4`)

Comment: Anyway, this doesn't look like a [mcve] of your problem because you don't describe what happens.  If you know why it's broken, explain which parts you know aren't doing what you want and need changing.  And what you want them to do for your asm implementation.

Comment: What assembler is this?  It looks like NASM syntax (with the `;` comments), but then you have stuff like `count[rsi]` instead of `[count + rsi]`.  And `mov rcx, Limit` looks like it should be a load, not a mov-immediate of the address like it would be in NASM syntax.